# Approximating a convergent series within an error

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

We need the following theorem, by the way I'm taking this problem from Boas' Mathematical Analysis:

**Theorem 14.4**: If $S = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$ converges for $|x| <1$, and if $|a_{n+1}| < |a_n|$ for $n > N$, then

$$ |S - \sum_{n=0}^{N} a_nx^n| < \frac{|a_{N+1}x^{N+1}|}{1 - |x|} $$

**Problem**: Show that $\frac{2}{\sqrt{4-x}}=1+ \frac{1}{8}x$ with an error less than $\frac{1}{32}$ for $0 <x < 1$.  $Hint$: Let $x=4y$, and use theorem $14.4$.

**My attempt**: Using their suggestion and messing around with series approximation, I was able to get the following

$$ \frac{2}{\sqrt{4-x}} = 1 + \frac{1}{8} x + \frac{3}{128}x^2 +...$$

So then using theorem $14.4$, setting $N=2$ we have:

$$ |\frac{2}{\sqrt{4-x}} - 1 - \frac{1}{8}x|< \frac{\frac{3}{128}x^2}{1- |x|}$$

The problem says for $0<x<1$. What value of x do I plug into the right side of the above inequality in order to get the following error, and why?

$$ |\frac{2}{\sqrt{4-x}} - 1 - \frac{1}{8}x|< \frac{1}{32}$$

Comment: The hint is to let $x = 4y$. Apply theorem 14.4 - check that its hypotheses are met - to the series in $y$. $0 < x < 1$ corresponds to $0 < y < \frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Thanks so much, I was converting it back into x at too early of a stage